# Django specific error on running code in settings.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to create an html file when the django project is started, by including code in the project/settings.py as follows:

```
def Brander():
    import configparser
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('settings.ini')
    version = config['PROJECT']['version']
    APPNAME = config['BRANDING']['appname']
    APPCOMPANY = config['BRANDING']['appcompany']
    APPCOMPANYLINK = config['BRANDING']['appcompanysite']
    APPLINK = config['BRANDING']['appsite']
    from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders
    filen = finders.find('clinic/brandedfooter.html')
    f = open(filen, "w")
    s = f"""
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 d-none d-md-block d-lg-block">
        <span class="text-muted float-right"><i>My OP and IP Clinic - <a href="{APPLINK}">{APPCOMPANY} by </a><a href="{APPCOMPANYLINK}">{APPCOMPANY}</a></i></span>
    </div>
    """
    f.write(s)
```

My project/settings.ini contains:

```
[PROJECT]
version = 0.0.1

[BRANDING]
appname = MyOPIP
appcompany = Droidzone
appcompanysite = https://droidzone.in
appsite = https://myopip.com
```

When the above code is run as standalone python script, everything works fine, and the html file is generated. However, when this is executed as part of `manage.py runserver`, I get the following error:

```
joel@hp:~/myappointments$ ./manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 325, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/joel/myappointments/myappointments/settings.py", line 258, in <module>
    Brander()
File "/home/joel/myappointments/myappointments/settings.py", line 16, in Brander
    version = config['PROJECT']['version']
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 959, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'PROJECT'
```

I'm unable to understand why this error occurs only on starting the code in django.

Comment: The relative path to the ini file is incorrect. Try giving the full path or check what the current working directory is and adapt the path accordingly. And IMHO it's not a good idea to add actual code to the settings.

Comment: @KlausD. Could you suggest an alternate way to add a version and company name to the footer, which is included several levels below the master template? I dont want to end up passing several variables or an object every time I need to call a view. My app has hundreds of views.

Comment: Template inheritance? Custom template tag? Context processor? Middleware? ...

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for the ideas

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Django Constance](https://django-constance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for defining the settings. For example:

```
CONSTANCE_CONFIG = {
    'VERSION': ('0.0.1', 'Version'),
}
```

Then add `'constance.context_processors.config'` in you context processors like the [documentation](https://django-constance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#django-templates) mentioned. Then use it in template:

```
{{ config.VERSION }}
```